# How do I ensure dependent configurations are initialized with Spring @Configuration annotation?

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to use @Configuration annotations to wire up my application but I keep getting a NullPointerException in one of the initializers because the bean it refers to is not yet initialized (I think).  I have tried specifying in the web.xml just the 'root' config class and also tried doing a package scan and neither seem to work.

Sorry about the big code dump.  *I tried to produce a much simpler set of classes to reproduce the issue, but of course, when I did that, everything worked fine.*  Here are my classes (imports elided):

DataSourceConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    public DataSourceConfig() {
        System.err.println("DataSourceConfig constructed...");
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        BasicDataSource bean = new BasicDataSource();
        bean.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        bean.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/observation");
        bean.setUsername("observation");
        bean.setPassword("*******");
        bean.setInitialSize(1);
        bean.setMaxActive(5);
        bean.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        System.err.println("dataSource bean initialized: " + bean.toString());
        return bean;
    }
}
```

HibernateConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(DataSourceConfig.class)
public class HibernateConfig {

    public HibernateConfig() {
        System.err.println("HibernateConfig constructing...");
    }

    @Autowired
    private DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;

    @Bean
    protected NamingStrategy namingStrategy() {
        return new ImprovedNamingStrategy();
    }

    private AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = null;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("dataSourceConfig")
    public AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        if (sessionFactoryBean == null) {
            sessionFactoryBean = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
NPE Here--> sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSourceConfig.dataSource()); 
            sessionFactoryBean.setSchemaUpdate(true);
            sessionFactoryBean.setNamingStrategy(namingStrategy());
            sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {
                    "com.newco.observations.domain",
                    "com.newco.observations.domain.*" });
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("hibernate.default_schema", "observation");
            props.setProperty("hibernate.dialect",
                    "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect");
            props.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
            sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(props);
            System.err.println("sessionFactory initialized");
        }
        return sessionFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("dataSourceConfig")
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate() {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSourceConfig.dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public ResourceTransactionManager txManager() {
        HibernateTransactionManager bean = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        bean.setSessionFactory((SessionFactory) sessionFactory().getObject());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("sessionFactory")
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate((SessionFactory) sessionFactory()
                .getObject());
    }
}
```

DaoConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
@Import(HibernateConfig.class)
public class DaoConfig {

    public DaoConfig()
    {
        System.err.println("DaoConfig constructing...");
    }

    private @Autowired HibernateConfig hibernateConfig;

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hibernateTemplate")
    public PhenomenonGroupDao phenomenonGroupDao()
    {
        PhenomenonGroupDaoImpl bean = new PhenomenonGroupDaoImpl();
        bean.setHibernateTemplate(hibernateConfig.hibernateTemplate());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hibernateTemplate")
    public PhenomenonDao phenomenonDao()
    {
        PhenomenonDaoImpl bean = new PhenomenonDaoImpl();
        bean.setHibernateTemplate(hibernateConfig.hibernateTemplate());
        return bean;
    }

    @Bean
    @DependsOn("hibernateTemplate")
    public DiscretePhenomenonDao discretePhenomenonDao()
    {
        DiscretePhenomenonDaoImpl bean = new DiscretePhenomenonDaoImpl();
        bean.setHibernateTemplate(hibernateConfig.hibernateTemplate());
        return bean;
    }


}
```

You can see from the System.err.println's and the @DependsOn annotations a kind of flailing about that I'm doing.

I can provide the full log if it's useful, but here is what I think are the relevant lines (with a little formatting to make it more readable (maybe)):

- 208  [Thread-0] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer
- Successfully enhanced com.bjk.observation.server.config.DaoConfig; enhanced class name is: com.bjk.observation.server.config.DaoConfig$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$96e1956
- 229  [Thread-0] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
- Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@185572a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor, daoConfig,com.bjk.observation.server.config.DataSourceConfig#0, dataSource, com.bjk.observation.server.config.HibernateConfig#0, namingStrategy, sessionFactory, jdbcTemplate, txManager, hibernateTemplate, phenomenonGroupDao, phenomenonDao, discretePhenomenonDao]; root of factory hierarchy DaoConfig constructing...
- 252  [Thread-0] INFO  org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory
- Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@185572a: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor, org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor, daoConfig, com.bjk.observation.server.config.DataSourceConfig#0, dataSource, com.bjk.observation.server.config.HibernateConfig#0, namingStrategy, sessionFactory, jdbcTemplate, txManager, hibernateTemplate, phenomenonGroupDao, phenomenonDao, discretePhenomenonDao]; root of factory hierarchy
- 253  [Thread-0] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader
- Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'daoConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.bjk.observation.server.config.HibernateConfig com.bjk.observation.server.config.DaoConfig.hibernateConfig; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.bjk.observation.server.config.HibernateConfig#0': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.bjk.observation.server.config.HibernateConfig]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 5):

The problem, I believe is here:

```
@Autowired
private DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;
```

You're not supposed to explicitly wire yourself with other `@Configuration`-annotated classes, but rather the beans that they produce. Spring will sort out the plumbing for you.

So replace the above field with the simpler:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;
```

Spring will fetch the `DataSource` from `DataSourceConfig` and transparently inject it into the field.

Similarly, replace

```
@Autowired 
private HibernateConfig hibernateConfig;
```

with

```
@Autowired 
private HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate;
```

You'll notice that the `@Configuration` style doesn't feel as nice when working with factory beans like `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`, since you often have to call `getObject()` on it yourself. Sometimes, it's more natural to use XML config, and mix it with the java config style.

Comment: I don't know why that would help exactly because classes marked with @Configuration are supposed to be beans in their own right.  Nonetheless, I tried as you suggested and although my error log is different, it still has to do with beans not getting initialized in the right order.  (Debugger confirms this.)

I take your point about @Configuration not being as nice for factory beans and in fact, I've fallen back on old reliable xml configuration, but I would still like to understand how it's _supposed_ to work.

Comment: @jhericks, I agree with you. We can also use Fully-qualified bean references with @Autowired along with Direct bean references with @Autowired. Both the approaches are valid.
`@Autowired
private DataSourceConfig dataSourceConfig;` // This is also valid

**Reference-** https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch04s02.html)